# jQuery Descendant Selectors and Multiple Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this jQuery selectors:

```
$(".class1 class11, .class2")....
```

that doesn't work. The **class11** is triggered, but the **class2** *is not*.

If I use them separately (),

```
$(".class1 class11")...
$(".class2")...
```

they work both.

Is this a common problem or am I missing something?

Thank's!

**EDIT 1**

Thank's all for the support!

You convinced me regarding the fact that there is no problem with the selectors, so I took a deeper look at the second selector.
I wrote it separately again but this time the it still didn't work.
I then realised that this is appended by a jQuery plugin, and I was trying to hadle it after ***$(document).ready()***, (at the same time with the plugin itself).
So, I have moved it after ***$(window).load()***, and it works now.

Thank's again!

Comment: You're missing the `.` in `.class11`, but you're doing that in both examples so that's not it. You're missing something else, that we can't comment on without seeing your markup, because the multiple selectors should work, as provided. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FePXd/)

Comment: should work, probably best to create a fiddle.js to demo

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would do

```
$(".class1 .class11, .class2") 
/* select both .class11 element/s nested in a .class1 element 
 * and element/s with  .class2 */
```

or

```
$(".class1.class11, .class2")
/* select element/s with both class1 and class11 and element/s with .class2 */
```

Answer (score 1):

It should have worked: see [link](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

do you have more as example?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have a typo in your first selector (i.e. shouldn't it be `.class1 .class11` rather than `.class1 class11`)

This works for me:

**HTML**

```
​<div class="class1">
 c1
  <div class="class11">c11</div>
</div>

<div class="class2">c2</div>
```

**JavaScript**​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

```
$(".class1 .class11, .class2").css({color: 'blue'});​​​​
```